# How can I make my React component dynamic?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

At the moment, there is a component that is essentially copied 4 times. I would like to make it more abstract, and simply render it 4 times, and pass in the dynamic data each time. The data that's passed into each component are state hooks.

With that being the goal, could I get some help on the implementation?

Here's what a component call looks like in the parent:

```
  const [allBlueItems, setAllBlueItems] = useState([]);
  const [selectedBlueItems, setSelectedBlueItems] = useState([]);
  const [allRedItems, setAllRedItems] = useState([]);
  const [selectedRedItems, setSelectedRedItems] = useState([]);

    <BlueSelection
      allBlueItems={allBlueItems}
      selectedBlueItems={setSelectedBlueItems}
      setSelectedBlueItems={selectedBlueItems}
    />

    <RedSelection
      allRedItems={allRedItems}
      selectedRedItems={setSelectedRedItems}
      setSelectedRedItems={selectedRedItems}
    />
```

Then, the `ItemSelection` component uses those useState values passed in as props to render data, and updates the state accordingly:

```
const BlueSelection = ({ allBlueItems, selectedBlueItems, setSelectedBlueItems }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
      setSelectedBlueItems([]);
    }
  }, []);
```

Then I repeat myself and implement the exact same code to handle the RedItem

```
const RedSelection = ({ allRedItems, selectedRedItems, setSelectedRedItems }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
      setSelectedRedItems([]);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: I don't see any duplicate code to make more abstract. Show us how you are repeating yourself and maybe we can help you come up with something better.

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to have state hooks being passed through as props like that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If they are all the same component logic then wouldn't declaring one and providing them an identity be sufficient? So far the only difference I see is a color being part of the name you call a specific "instance" of the selection component.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne I'm trying to share state across components

Comment: @DrewReese I know, that's what I thought, but I get an error saying that setSelectedRedItems isn't passed in. I feel like it's related to me using a state hook.

Comment: Don't pass state updater functions since this offloads the responsibility for maintaining any state invariants to consuming components. Define a handler in the parent component and pass that instead, this allows the parent to maintain control over state updates. What are you asking for help with implementing? The parent logic? The children logic?

Comment: If you're trying to share the state across components, either use redux (which you have as a tag for this thread), or as @DrewReese said, have a handler in the parent components to handle the state changes and then pass the state through as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor

```
export default const Selection = () => {
     const [allItems, setAllItems] = useState([]);
      const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);
    
return (
        <Selection
          allItems={allItems}
          selectedItems={setSelectedItems}
          setSelectedItems={selectedItems}
        />)}
```

import this wherever you need it like....

```
import Selection as RedSelection from ...
import Selection as BlueSelection from...
```